# C pointers with arrays in functions with realloc

Tags: c

Hi
I am slowly getting my head around pointers and indirection but am still having a little trouble.

In my `main` function i am creating an array of structs (computers) using `malloc`

```
int arraySize = 0;//This may be the first issue
Computer    *ptrComputer = NULL; 
ptrComputer = (Computer*) malloc(sizeof(Computer) * arraySize);
```

I am then passing the pointer to a function that reads data out of a file and into the array

```
arraySize = readFileToArray(&ptrComputer, arraySize);

int readFileToArray(Computer **compArray, int arraySize){

Computer newComp;
int foundARecord = 0;
/*File stuff*/

   arraySize = extendArrays(compArray, arraySize, no_elements);

    /*Use fscanf to read file data into the newComputer variable*/
    printf("g %i\n", arraySize);
    *compArray[arraySize - 1] = newComp;//set the newly created part of the array to newComputer


return arraySize;
}

int extendArrays(Computer **compArray, int arraySize){
   arraySize++;
   //Resize the computer array
   *compArray = (Computer*)realloc(*compArray, (sizeof(Computer)*(arraySize + 1)));
   return arraySize;
}
```

Now as far as i understand, i am passing the address of ptrComputer to the `readFileToArray()` function. It is then passing that same address to the `extendArrays()` function which resizes it. I am then trying to assign newComp to the location in memory that compArray points to. This works as long as i try to write to index 0 but any others cause xcode to throw an exc_bad_access error. This is all very confusing, can anyone with a bit of experience with this see where i am going wrong? It was working before when i was passing the actual pointer to the `readFile` function but it only worked once (think i was reallocating a copy of the pointer)
Any help would be very muchly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: The first thing you should have done was check the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't immediately assign the return value of `realloc` to `*compArray`, as it may return `NULL`, in which case the former value of `*compArray` is still valid.

Comment: I do have checking implemented on both, just didnt include them to keep the size of the code down

Comment: Do not cast the return value of `malloc`. Casting the return value of `malloc` serves no purpose and may hide errors the compiler would catch otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
    *compArray[arraySize - 1] = newComp;//set the newly created part of the array to newComputer
```

Try this:

```
    (*compArray)[arraySize - 1] = newComp;//set the newly created part of the array to newComputer
```

This way you explicitly dereference compArray before subscripting.

Comment: That appears to have done it, thank you so much. Could you please explain the difference between the two?

Comment: The array subscripting operator has a higher precedence than the dereferencing operator. So *x[i] evaluates as *(x[i]), not (*x)[i].

Comment: So the way i was doing was trying to deference compArray[arraySize - 1] instead of just compArray